# Array reference behavior in PHP

Tags: php

For the life of me, I can't understand this godforsaken language. This:

```
$x = explode(' ', 'a b c');
echo $x[0];
```

works just fine. But:

```
echo explode(' ', 'a b c')[0];
```

returns an error. What gives?

Comment: `echo current(explode(' ', 'a b c'));`

Comment: @biakaveron this won't work for [1] :)

Comment: Yep, but the question is about getting first element :p

Comment: +1 biakaveron: I have used that little trick before, but not many people know about the current() function

Comment: @biakaveron, the question is about why it gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax isn't supported by the PHP parser, yet. It is called array dereferencing and has been added in the PHP trunk already.

Comment: Funny! So PHP parser and trunk developers are out of sync! PHP Parser team had better move fastly!

Comment: Not quite true, I believe it is added to the trunk for the new PHP version which can be 5.4 or 6.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply *a syntax error*, you can use the array brackets `[]` only on variables in PHP.

Example:

```
echo $x[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do that in PHP 5.4**... it's time to upgrade.

Per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

```
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```